# latexmk mv logs to /tmp

Tags: latexmk

if I use

```
latexmk --output-directory=/tmp
```

then it moves all outputs, including pdf files to `/tmp`.  What I am trying is to move `log`, `fls`, `fdb_latexmk` etc to be moved,  but keeping `aux`, `bbl`, `pdf` to be in the same directory. I can write a script no doubt, but is it possible within `latexmk`?

Comment: Does the provided answer solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Well, the [latexmk-documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/latexmk/) is pretty clear on this:

> **-auxdir=FOO** or **-aux-directory=FOO**
> Sets the directory for auxiliary output files of (pdf)latex (.aux,
> .log etc).  This achieves its effect bythe -aux-directory option of
> (pdf)latex, which currently is only implemented on the MiKTeX ver-sion
> of (pdf)latex.

Following this you should be able to move the files you don't want to

```
latexmk -auxdir=/tmp your_file.tex
```

Comment: oh...sorry. you are absolutely correct. I missed the point to tell that i am using `lualatex`. Sorry for that.

Comment: I only have texlive. Does passing the `-lualatex`-flag work? `latexmk -auxdir=./tmp -lualatex your_file.tex`

Comment: not completely. as per my test, aux, fdb_latexmake moved, but not log, fdl etc. I am in texlive also. As a vim user, I am moving it using `au` now. which is working.

Comment: @BaRud, if you don't need the extra files, you can also pass `-c`-flag for clean. This should get rid of unneeded files.

Comment: yes, obviously that is what I am doing with quitepre.

Comment: Small comment: Although the documentation says '(pdf)latex' in many places, it should be '*latex', i.e., the option is equally valid for all engines, including xelatex and lualatex. The documentation will be updated in the next release to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: As already mentioned, the solution of using the `-auxdir=...` is currently supported only with the MiKTeX distribution and but not with the TeXLive distribution that is being used by the OP.  However it is possible to configure `latexmk` to emulate MiKTeX's behavior.  See http://personal.psu.edu/jcc8//latexmk/versions.html and find where the file `fix-aux.latexmkrc` is referred to.  This item has just been added to the webpage. I hope to incorporate this method in a future release of `latexmk`.

Comment: @JohnCollins, thank you for your comments, they are much appreciated. I would love to ammend my answer using your hints and links, but will only do so if you don't object.

Comment: @phil-elkabat Do go ahead.  If I have something to add, I can edit the answer.